# get a point on a bezier curve without guessing or brute force

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, bezier

I originally wanted to use four points (as a bezier Curve is defined with 4 points), but that forces me to brute force the position, so I tried a different approach i now need help with:

I have a start point P0, an end point P1 and slopes m0 and m1 which are supposed to give me the start/end slope to calculate a Bezier Curve inbetween them.
The Curve is supposed to be in the form of a function (3rd degree), since I need to get the height y of a given point x.

Using the **HTML5Canvas** i can draw a bezier curve no problem and using this function

[image]

that allows me to calculate any given point given a percentage of the way i can get the center point of the curve. But I don't need it depending on t but rather the y depending on x, so not halfway of the curve but halfway of the x distance between P0 and P1.

Image to visualize:
[image]
Left is what i can calculate, right is what i need.

I've been trying to calculate the cubic function given the two points P0, P1 as well as the slopes m0, m1, which results into four equations which i can't seem to be able to solve with only variable inputs. I've also tried to use the above function to calculate the t using the x value (which is known), but no dice there either.

I need to avoid using approximations or costly loops for these calculations as they are performed many times a second for many objects, thus [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18541178/get-a-point-inside-bezier-curve) is not feasible for me.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to everyone that answered before, those are generally great solutions.

In my case I can be 100% sure that I can convert the curve into a cubic function, which serves as the approximation of the bezier curve using [the result of this calculation](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3173881/660441).

Since i have control over my points in my case, I can force the P0 to be on x=0, which simplifies the linear system calculations and thus allows me to calculate the cubic function much easier like this:

```js
let startPoint: Utils.Vector2 = new Utils.Vector2(0, 100);
let endPoint: Utils.Vector2 = new Utils.Vector2(100, 100);


let a: number, b: number, c: number, d: number;

function calculateFunction() {
    let m0: number = 0;
    let m1: number = 0;

    a = (-endPoint.x * (m0 + m1) - 2 * startPoint.y + 2 * endPoint.y) / -Math.pow(endPoint.x, 3);
    b = (m1 - m0 - 3 * a * Math.pow(endPoint.x, 2)) / (2 * endPoint.x);
    c = m0;
    d = startPoint.y;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered the same problem in a project I'm working on. I don't know of a formula to get the `y` coordinate from the `x`, and I suspect you'll have trouble with that route because a bezier curve can have up to 3 points that all have the same x value.

I would recommend using the library BezierEasing, which was designed for this use case and uses various performance enhancing techniques to make lookups as fast as possible: https://github.com/gre/bezier-easing

Answer (score 1):

To solve this problem, you need to rewrite Bezier equation in power polynomial form

```
X(t) = t^3 * (P3.X-3*P2.X+3*P1.X-P0.X) + 
       t^2 * (3*P0.X + 6*P1.X+3*P2.X) + 
       t * (3*P1.X - 3P2.X) +
       P0.X 

if X(t) = P0.X*(1-ratio) + P3.X*ratio 
then
let d = ratio * (P0.X - P3.X)
```

and solve [cubic equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function) for unknown t

```
a*t^3 + b*t^2 + c*t + d = 0
```

[JS code here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27176423/function-to-solve-cubic-equation-analytically)

Then apply calculated `t` parameter (there might be upto three solutions) to Y-component and get point coordinates. Note that formulas are close (no loops) and should work fast enough